# How to execute an application with test results after MSTest?

Tags: testing, msbuild, mstest, target

Anyway to have my project run a application after the test batch finished?

I was hoping to add a <Target> but was unable to find anything.

I am just wanting to pass the results to a seperate executable to parse into an html once my test is completed... perhaps a AfterTest target?

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to run [trx2html](http://trx2html.codeplex.com/) ?

Then this applies to you: [TestResults Reports in TFS Builds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rido/archive/2007/05/24/testresults-reports-in-tfs-builds.aspx)

In case of another executable, just follow the same instructions and replace trx2html by your alternative executable.